# Where to add Content Type - application/JSON in html form? Error - Unable to decode JSON data

Tags: html, json, api, postman

I need to pass json file to API but it looks like I need to do something to the JSON file before it send to the API. The error is "Unable to decode JSON data".

```
<form name="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="https://api-106.dxi.eu/ecnow.php" method="POST" enctype='application/json'>
    <input type="hidden" name="method" value="ecnow_records">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="create">
    <input type="hidden" name="format" value="json">
    <input type="hidden" name="raw" value="1">

    Send this file: <input name="easycall" type="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Send json File">
</form>
```

It works fine when I tried with Postman and pasted the JSON into Body->Raw. I am not sure where exactly the Body->Raw represent in HTML form?

Please advise.

Thank in advance

Comment: You are using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form. BTW, you can't use raw JSON body here because you have input field file.

Comment: thank. So what kind of of enctype can i use.

Comment: Browsers won't support `enctype='application/json'` as of now. The default value will be URL Form encoded. For ref, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype. Please use ajax request to send the json as raw payload.

Comment: Thank u. Suresh. Can you give me any example of ajax code? I am totally lost.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I get it working way. Thank for your helps.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $.getJSON('dataset.json', function (data) {

             $.ajax({                    
                    url: "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    xhrFields: 'withCredentials:true',
                    type: "POST",
                    data:  JSON.stringify(data),
                    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("success"+data);
                    },
                    error: function (xhRequest, ErrorText, thrownError) {
                        alert("Failed to process correctly, please try again");
                    }
                });



        });
```